# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to servername:80

Tags: git, gitlab

Only one user in windows is getting this error, Error occurs during pull/clone.
     Error
     fatal: unable to access 'https://username:password@servername/path/project.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to servername:80 Error: Return (1) from RunCommand.

Comment: I wonder if you can work around the error by adding an explicit port (`...servername:443`) to the URL?